# Django - create object in a specific database

Tags: python, django, django-models

To save a model to my `'not_default_db'` I'm using :

```
 p = Person(name='James')
 p.save(using='not_default_db')
```

But using **Model.create()** save the model in the default DB:

```
Person.objects.create(name='James')
```

Is it possible to use **Model.create()** on a specifc Data Base ?

Comment: You have to specify multiple database in your settings.py file. You can read the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/). Then, I suspect issue in your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use queryset's [`using()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#using) method:

```
Person.objects.using('not_default_db').create(name='James')
```